# Python .drop() pandas is not deleting the csv row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, selenium

i'm a newbie coder(first month), i'm trying to create a simple script that can login into instagram, so the script will take the ID and password from a CSV file and do the login on instagram, this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyperclip
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Downloads/scraping2.csv')
print(df)
def instagram_login():
    print(df.to_string())
    df2=df.at[0,'ID'] #Find the first row id
    pyperclip.copy(df2) #Copy the first row id to the clipboard
    print(pyperclip.paste()) #Print the first row id
    #apro il sito
    driver=uc.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
    driver.maximize_window() #schermo intero
    consent= driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button[2]").click() #clicco il consenso
    time.sleep(5)
    put_username = driver.find_element(By.NAME,("username")).send_keys(pyperclip.paste()) #inserisco username
    df2=df.at[0,'PASSWORD'] #Trova password
    pyperclip.copy(df2) #Copia password
    put_password = driver.find_element(By.NAME,("password")).send_keys(pyperclip.paste()) #inserisco password
    login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/button").click() #clicco login
    time.sleep(6)
    try:
        phone_request = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div[1]/div/p") #clicco su non adesso
        if phone_request.is_displayed(): #se è visibile la richiesta telefonica vai avanti
            df.drop([2], axis=0,inplace=True) #elimina la prima riga
            df
            print(df)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        wrong_password = driver.find_element(By.ID,"slfErrorAlert")
        print(wrong_password.text)
        df.drop([2],inplace=True) #elimina la prima riga
        print(df)
    except:
        pass
        
instagram_login()
```

The problem is that here:

```
wrong_password = driver.find_element(By.ID,"slfErrorAlert")
        print(wrong_password.text)
        df.drop([2],inplace=True) #elimina la prima riga
        print(df)
```

df.drop seem not working.

what am i doing wrong?

i need that for every try on instagram login page, after that the script finish the operation, the first row will be deleted from the CSV

Answer (score 0):

Usually you try to avoid looping through DataFrames, especially with such simple functions like you are trying to call. I personally would recommend using `df.apply(my_function, axis=1)` instead. It will apply your function to every row. Example:

```py
def login(input: dict):
    # here you can run your login stuff, and access the row values via input
    username = input['username_column_name']
    password = input['password_column_name']

df.apply(login, axis=1)
```

for further details read through the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Aside from this, if you still want your original question answered, I need more information on why you are thinking `df.drop(...)` is not working.

Comment: i need to bulk login instagram profiles, so every Instagram account in the csv need to login. i've tried everything but cannot understand what is wrong with my code and why cannot delete the row with df.drop